# error occurred while loading required library hostpolicy.dll

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core-migrations

I would to like update the database but when i run : 'update-datebase' or the command : `add-migiration' in the Package Manager Console it give this error

```
Failed to load the dll from 
[C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.7\hostpolicy.dll], 
HRESULT: 0x800700C1
An error occurred while loading required library hostpolicy.dll from 
[C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.7]
```

Things that have been done:

- Update .Net Core to 2.2.7
- Remove .Net Core 3.
- Run VS(2017 & 2019) in administrator mode

Update nucket packages

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore v2.2.6
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools V 2.2.6

Comment: The file "C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.7\hostpolicy.dll" exists?

Comment: Yea that exists